# Copying files - Destination path too long: How to fix folders that didnt copy

Tags: windows-7

Moving contents of an old external hard drive to Win 7 machine.

Target Directory is about 10 characters long.

Copied all directories at once and operation finished with dialogue saying 6032 files have too long a path.

Chose to skip for all.

Now I need to find and remedy all these folders/files that didn't copy across.

At the moment my ideas are:

Idea #1
 Identify the folders in the source (hopefully not too many) and deal
    with each by manually to shorten the destination path. Some
    comparison utility to identify and log the folders that didn't get
    copied will be needed.

Idea #2
Create a folder in the destination drive with a one character name
    (say "x") and try the copy again.

What is the best approach to dealing with this type of issue?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was creating a remote drive in the source from the "middle" of the path, for instance:

Subst w: C:/waytoolongpath/insanelylong

Then I continue the copy from w:

I don't remember the subst syntax by heart but that might work.